# Should there be a separate site for questions related to mobile phone development?

Tags: discussion

The volume of questions on Stack Overflow is large. I think we should have a separate website for asking questions related to mobile phone related development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SO is about programming on ALL platforms, mac, windows, linux, all on one site. The reason superuser and serverfault were made is because they're a different subject, computers in general and server administration, respectively. :D

Comment: can you elaborate more on why serverfault or superuser were made

Comment: Basically: SO-- All types of programming; SF-- All types of servers; SU-- Anything else having to do with computers

Answer (score 2):

NO.  Proof by counterexample: I have never wrote a single mobile program, but I answered a question about Android with just use of mere Linux knowledge.  Many concepts between mobile, embedded and "usual" development are shared throughout these domains.

It's just more logical to have them all in one place.

Comment: This is true also with some iPhone questions which can be answered by Mac developers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.  I don't think there's enough volume plus people will invariably continue to post mobile phone dev questions on SO.